# Make graph rooted

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, directed-graph

**definition for the question:** a node v will be called "root" iff for each node u in the graph there is a directed path from v to u.

given a directed graph G= without any "root" in it.

i need to find an algorithm that decides if we can add one edge so that there will be a "root" in the resulting graph.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute the strongly connected component (SCC) graph for your graph.  If that SCC graph has exactly two sources A and B, adding a directed edge from any node in A to any node in B will result in every node in A being a "root" node in the final graph.

A source is a node that has no incoming edges.

You can compute the SCC graph in O(|V| + |E|) time using [Tarjan's SCC algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm). So the overall complexity is O(|V| + |E|).

Comment: can you explain exactly how this algorithm solve this problem? in each scc in Gscc, there is a directed path between any pair of nodes. I think that i can find a graph which have more than two scc's and still if we will add a edge between two specific nodes there will be a "root" in the resulting graph.

Comment: @baza "If that SCC graph has exactly two **sources**..." - not exactly two **nodes**. Each node in the SCC graph is a collection of nodes in the original graph.